# What is a Protestant understanding of Jesus' fasting in the wilderness?

Tags: protestantism, gospel-of-matthew, fasting

According to mainline Protestantism (Lutheran, Anglican, Reformed, Methodist) what is the reason why Jesus fasted for 40 days in the wilderness (Matthew 4:1-11):

> Then Jesus was led by the Spirit into the wilderness to be tempted[a]
> by the devil. 2 After fasting forty days and forty nights, he was
> hungry. 3 The tempter came to him and said, “If you are the Son of
> God, tell these stones to become bread. [...]

Does Jesus teach us here that we should fast as a discipline? Why did Jesus do this?

Comment: There is nothing in any of the four evangelists' accounts which would lead one to suppose that one is to do as Jesus did. I suggest the question should focus on another aspect of the Lord's temptation.

Comment: @NigelJ that’s fine! You can included that in your answer. However, the main question is, why did Jesus do it?

Comment: There is one question in the Title and two different questions in the Body.

Comment: The question asks for a *Protestant* understanding, but doesn't supply a *Catholic* understanding or explain why one might think it would be different.

Comment: @RayButterworth I just assumed catholics would put more influence on fasting, since it's a requirement in their church, as opposed to Protestants who have it more relaxed.